# Excluding a directory via dockerfile in nodejs app

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a nodejs app and I did containerized it with docker. Here is my dockerfile :

```
FROM node:14.17.0-alpine
WORKDIR /nodejs
COPY src/* .
COPY app.js .
COPY package*.json /nodejs/
COPY . .
RUN npm install

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

As you can see I am copying everything, but I want to exclude node_modules folder. What should I add to the dockerfile in order to tell to to igonore that dir?

**UPDATE**
As mentioned in the comments, I need the .ignorefile to exclude the node_module forlder.I have already used this line :

```
**/node_modules
```

in .dockerignore but did not work.

my folder structure :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A17PA.png

Comment: have you used a `.ignorefile` file or `.dockerignore` file?

Comment: I actually used .dockerignore file

Comment: please add your folder structure

Comment: Ok I did add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's the purpose of the .dockerignore file, you can either create one or copy specific folders by name or directory.

**UPDATE:**

After getting more information it is clear that the path to the folder to be ignored is misplaced,

replace

```
**/node_modules
```

with

```
node_modules
```

or

```
./node_modules*
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that it can not be done without .ignorefile?

Comment: why wouldn't you use that file? if you have some specific situation please elaborate, otherwise you should use the feature the product added

Comment: Noam Yizraeli, I just updated the question, can you please provide me with a new answer so to accept it.